# Convert a string into a JS object that is not formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is not formatted correctly, using JavaScript, let's say the data is:

```
{engine{type{condition},age},wheels,model{name},color}
```

And I want to convert that to a usable (JS) object. I could use regex to parse out pieces, but I'm wondering if there's a non-regex method to do so. If you had to do it in regex, what would be the easiest way of doing it?

Converted object should be something more like:

```
{
 engine: {
  type: {
   condition: null
  },
  age: null
 },
 wheels: null,
 model: {
  name: null
 },
 color: null
}
```

I could also work with it from a series of nested arrays.

Comment: Do you mean convert an ill-formed JSON object with keys only / no values into a proper JSON object?

Comment: Yes, slotting nulls underneath the values possibly.

Comment: Write a little parser for your little language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, under the assumption that that "char{" should be "char:{" and "char," or"char}" should be "char=null," or "char=null}", this is a pretty simple find and replace. Otherwise, you might have to use a recursive parse function to rip it apart and put it back together again.

```js
var str = "{engine{type{condition},age},wheels,model{name},color}"
str = str.replace(/([A-z])\s*{/g, "$1:{")
str = str.replace(/([A-z])\s*([},])/g, "$1:null$2")
console.log(str);
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that, replacing ending bits with proper terminators would probably work really well and avoid a recursive function.

Comment: @Organiccat The best solutions are often the simplest (and performance wise, this is basically just a walk-through of the text)